# How to do 'Generate DDL' in Sybase Central in isql on the command line?

Tags: sybase, isql

In Sybase Central when I right click on a stored procedure and choose 'Generate DDL', then I see the definition of the stored procedure, but also the grants for example.

How do you do that on the command line with isql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best/recommended approach would be the [ddlgen](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_ASE/da6c1d172bef4597a78dc5e81a9bb947/a7ed349ebc2b1014b50fbd20d6921128.html?locale=en-US) utility program; this will generate the DDL for the proc's text, `sp_procxmode` settings, and permissions. `ddlgen` is the 'go to' tool for reverse engineering `Sybase ASE` DDL.

Sample run:

```
$ ddlgen -SASE400 -Ppassword -Usa -TP -Nsybsystemprocs.dbo.sp_helptext

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- DDL for Stored Procedure 'sybsystemprocs.dbo.sp_helptext'
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

print '<<<<< CREATING Stored Procedure - "sybsystemprocs.dbo.sp_helptext" >>>>>'
go

use sybsystemprocs
go

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sysobjects o, sysusers u WHERE o.uid=u.uid AND o.name = 'sp_helptext' AND u.name = 'dbo' AND o.type = 'P')
BEGIN
        setuser 'dbo'
        drop procedure sp_helptext

END
go

IF (@@error != 0)
BEGIN
        PRINT 'Error dropping Stored Procedure sybsystemprocs.dbo.sp_helptext'
        SELECT syb_quit()
END
go

setuser 'dbo'
go


/*
** sp_helptext
**

... snip ...

*/
create or replace procedure sp_helptext(
                  @objname              varchar(325)    = NULL
                , @grouping_num         int             = NULL
                , @numlines             int             = NULL
                , @printopts            varchar(256)    = NULL
                , @trace                int             = 0
) as

... snip ...

return (0)
end

go

Grant Execute on dbo.sp_helptext to public Granted by dbo
go

sp_procxmode 'sp_helptext', anymode
go

setuser
go
```

Other options would include:

- [defncopy](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_ASE/da6c1d172bef4597a78dc5e81a9bb947/a7f105d8bc2b1014b2aad75af138df4a.html?locale=en-US) utility program for the text of the proc
- [sp_helptext](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_ASE/29a04b8081884fb5b715fe4aa1ab4ad2/ab6ecec1bc2b101496229adb2a694f43.html?locale=en-US) for text of the proc
- [sp_helprotect](https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_ASE/29a04b8081884fb5b715fe4aa1ab4ad2/ab6e3715bc2b1014a9eabc7a3ff7eafc.html?locale=en-US) for permissions (though you will need to parse the output to generate the necessary `grant/revoke` commands)